# Execute Result of Dynamic Postgres Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, materialized-views

I have a table in my postgres db called rpt.view_refresh_schedule. This table contains the name of materialized views stored in my database that I would like to refresh on a schedule.

I have written the query below which takes each record in the rpt.view_refresh_schedule table and builds a dynamic query to refresh each table.

```
select CONCAT('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || view_name || ';') as script from rpt.view_refresh_schedule
```

The output of that query is as follows:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_user_trading_activity;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_orders;
```

I want to create a function that executes the dynamic queries that were produced as a result of my above sql. How can I do that? I have seen other posts which execute a query from a single string but this is multiple commands. In python I would just loop over the results and execute each one. Is there something similar in postgres? I have tried the LOOP function with no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using psql, you can do this, without having to write a function:

```
select CONCAT('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || view_name || ';') as script from rpt.view_refresh_schedule
\gexec
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
  cmd text;
BEGIN
  FOR cmd in select CONCAT('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || view_name) as script 
               from rpt.view_refresh_schedule 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE cmd;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your refresh schedule is truly dynamic meaning you update your table for a given materialized view often you do not need either function nor table. If you refresh interval is stable, for a given MV, you can define it on the [create](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#i2064161) or [alter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2002.htm#SQLRF00808) materialized view. From the documentation section create_mv_refresh on create:

> Use the create_mv_refresh clause to specify the default methods,
> modes, and times for the database to refresh the materialized view. If
> the master tables of a materialized view are modified, then the data
> in the materialized view must be updated to make the materialized view
> accurately reflect the data currently in its master tables. This
> clause lets you schedule the times and specify the method and mode for
> the database to refresh the materialized view.